# css shadows not applied correctly in bottom of images

Tags: html, image, css, shadows

I'm working on an homepage with this html/css: http://jsfiddle.net/2qWYf/5/

I can't figure out why the shadows I applied to the images are start to showing some pixels under the image bottom line.

In the right side instead it's ok (!?!) Why?

How to fix this?

Many thanks, Alessandro

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are applying the shadow to the element that surrounds the image (and the link), and that is the size of that element.

The reason, in turn, why that element is that size, is because the image is an inline element which is placed on the base line of a text block. The space below the image is the gutter below the baseline for hanging characters like `g` and `j`.

The most stable way to handle this is to turn the images into block elements:

```
.homepageimage img { display: block; }
```

(The surrounding anchor element is already a block element as you have applied `float: left;` to it, otherwise you would need to turn that into a block element too.)

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height: 0px` to `.homepageimage a` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4hwUd/)).

Comment: @Matt Ball - Not everything in the world needs a demo!  :)

Comment: Lies, damned lies. And statistics.

Comment: Ah crap, my profile says I downvoted you, but I don't even remember doing so (or see any reason why). Might have been an accident, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to fix this, however, two stand out for me:

Simply add a height of 200px to `.homepageimage`. Example:

```
.homepageimage {
    height: 200px;
}
```

...or add `margin-bottom: -3px;` to `.homepageimage a`. Example:

```
.homepageimage a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this is a hack that isn't guaranteed to work should other things be changed (like body font size)

Comment: @cwolves: Using the "height method" seems to work properly, even with a font change

Comment: That wasn't there before!  :)  Still not a great solution since it relies on the image being 200px tall.  Better to fix the problem than to patch it